# Not getting name Attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am not getting value from name Attribute. What I am doing wrong?

For example

```
$(function() {
    $("#orderForm").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var statusName = $(this).attr('input[name="name"]').val();
        var statusDesc = $(this).attr('input[name="description"]').val();
        alert(statusName);
    });
});
```

HTML Code:

```
<form id='orderForm'>
   <input type="text" name="name">
  <textarea name="description"></textarea>
 <button type="Submit">Add</button>
</form>
```

Comment: `attr` needs an attribute name as an argument, not a selector, as far as I know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are searching for [`attribute equals selector`](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/),

```
$("#orderForm").submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var statusName = $('input[name="name"]', this).val();
  var statusDesc = $('textarea[name="description"]', this).val();
  alert(statusName);
});
```

And here i have used `$("selector", context)` version, So the elements which matches the selector would be searched inside the context not out of it. And it is very similar to `$(context).find("selector")`

Comment: Thanks. This mean input will be searched outside of `#orderForm`

Comment: Out of interest, why use `$('input[name="name"]', this).val()` as opposed to just `$('input[name="name"]').val()`

Comment: @DarrenSweeney Can you have a look at my answer. I was typing it. :)

Comment: @I'll-Be-Back That is why we have provided the `context`. That means the elements will be searched inside of `form` not outside of it.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy That's very cool and new to me - thanks for that

Comment: $('input[name="description"] ) may not work for textarea, it should be  $('textarea[name="description"]) or $('*[name="description"])

Comment: @miketracker Man, you have a sharp pair of eyes. I didn't notice that. Fixed it. :)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery `attr` function get the value of an attribute, not the value of an text input.

You should use `children()` for get the user input value of the `orderForm` module. I prepared a [Js Bin](https://jsbin.com/loburufige/edit?html,css,js,output) with the correct code.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
$(function() {
  $("#orderForm").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var statusName = $(this).find('input[name="name"]').val();
    var statusDesc = $(this).find('*[name="description"]').val();
// or var statusDesc = $(this).find('textarea[name="description"]').val();
    alert(statusDesc);
  });
});
```

i would recommend you to assign Id's for each field while dealing with forms